# How to set a different Phpunit environment variable?

Tags: php, phpunit, circleci

In our code we have line:

```
if (Configure::read('environment') != 'live') {
    ConnectionManager::alias(Configure::read('environment'), 'default');
}
```

This means that whenever our code is not on live, our connection is going to be set as 'default' and we have this connection in `app.php`

I have a problem with that.

Since we are using CircleCI and our PhpUnit code fails and it gets reverted every time.

So I need to set for PhpUnit different environment variable (I need it to use 'test', not 'default').

Already tried: 
Scenario -

```
<php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    <env name="test" value="test"/>
</php>
```

Inside the `phpunit.xml.dist`, I have set `<env name='test' value='test'/>` hoping that this is going to set for phpunit different environment.

My question is how to set different environments for PhpUnit and for the rest of the code ? Or let me rephrase it, how could I use different environment variable for CircleCi and PhpUnit and our code ?

Comment: what the `Configure::read` do? can you show the code?

Comment: Please confirm `Configure::read('environment')` returns value from environment variable (which one?), not from the config file.

Comment: It is a cakephp core class.
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#namespace-Cake\Core
I think it returns the configuration from the database config.

Comment: Hi, i don't know cakephp but seems that the configurations key are loaded from a configuration files so you can simply define a different config file for the circleci build

Comment: Hmm, could you be more detailed ?

Answer (score 0):

if the `Configure::read` read from the env with the [getenv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function, you could use the env like:

```
    <php>
      <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
      <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
      <env name="environment" value="test"/>
    </php>
```

You could create a different configuration file like phpunit-circleci.xml and use it as argument like:

> phpunit -c phpunit-circleci.xml

Hope this help

Comment: It doesn't read from the getenv function. That's my problem. :-/