# How to set Enviorment Variables for Symfony 4 with PHP and XAMPP in Windows

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, composer-php, symfony4

I am working on a Symfony 4.4 project.

I need to run scripts on my local enviorment.

The CLI to run `phpunit` is `APP_ENV=test phpdbg -d memory_limit=-1 -qrr vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --coverage-text`

But the problem is that I dont know how to properly set APP_ENV variable because I get this error:

> APP_ENV=test : The term 'APP_ENV=test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The file for database connection is:

**.env.test.local:**

```
APP_ENV=test

database_host="localhost"
database_port="3306"
database_name="xxx_test"
database_user="root"
database_password=""
```

Comment: Please share more details. How do you call this script, and do you use Windows or Linux? Why not set the environment in `phpunit.xml` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542229/how-to-set-a-different-phpunit-environment-variable)?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `APP_ENV` in your `phpunit.xml.dist` file:

```
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
</php>
```

Comment: @talhaamir, if this is the correct answer, please accept it as the answer. thanks.